# 2 people running around a track at different speeds problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Cristy and Christa run around a circular track. They both start running from the same place in opposite directions at constant speeds.
>
> They first meet each other after Cristy has run $200$ meters. They meet again $50$ seconds later.
>
> If Christa runs $1.5$ times faster than Cristy, Christa's speed? Give your answer in meters per second rounded to the nearest tenth.

So what I did was I saw that every time they meet, they run the same distance which is $200$ meters for Cristy meaning that $200/50$ is $4$ meters per second and that times $1.5$ is $6$m/s. I just wanted to make sure I was correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried? Are you stuck at some particular step? Is your answer wrong? Questions showing no effort tend to be voted down and/or closed

Comment: Welcome to [math.se].
Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem?
If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[ask], on 
[formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) 
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Ok editing it rn

Comment: The answer is indeed $6.0$m/s.

Comment: ok thanks because what threw me off was round to the tenth

Comment: That's why I wrote $6.0$m/s instead of $6$m/s. ;)